# Plotting interaction based on regression results

Tags: r, plot, regression, interaction, cox-regression

I am trying to figure out how to create a plot illustrating how an interaction term affect the hazard ratio based on the results from a performed regression.

I have tried searching, but most pages seem to explain how to illustrate interactions between different variables in the data set, and, unfortunately, not how they affect the regression results.

As an example, I have created the model below

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.karno*sex + ph.ecog, data=lung)
```

from which I get the following results

```
> summary(fit)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.karno * sex + ph.ecog, 
    data = lung)

  n= 226, number of events= 163 
   (2 observations deleted due to missingness)

                 coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
ph.karno      0.03680   1.03748  0.01969  1.869 0.061618 .  
sex           1.16232   3.19735  1.14403  1.016 0.309636    
ph.ecog       0.61842   1.85599  0.18064  3.424 0.000618 ***
ph.karno:sex -0.02148   0.97874  0.01415 -1.518 0.129033    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

             exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
ph.karno        1.0375     0.9639    0.9982     1.078
sex             3.1974     0.3128    0.3396    30.102
ph.ecog         1.8560     0.5388    1.3026     2.644
ph.karno:sex    0.9787     1.0217    0.9520     1.006
```

I would then like to create a plot illustrating how the interaction between `ph.karno` and `sex`affect the hazard ratio.

I would assume that the `ph.karno` values would run along the x-axis while the two `sex` values would be marked by two different lines, and that the effet on the hazard ratio would somehow by represented by the y-axis.

However, I fall short on how to actually perform this in R, and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_interactions.html), [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactions/vignettes/interactions.html), and [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/seminars/interactions-r/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I can see, the packages unfortunately does not work with a cox regression?